# Spring web flux rest api - working in local computer but throwing "Not allowed to capture 'id' twice in the same pattern" on deploying in open shift

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have written an API which works fine on local computer but throws an exception when deployed in open shift environment.

Code -

```
@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routes() {
    return  route()
            .path("/student", builder -> builder
                    .GET("/output/{id}", accept(APPLICATION_JSON), req -> ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                            .body(Mono.justOrEmpty(studentService.getPayload(req.pathVariable("id"))), String.class)))
            .build();
}
```

Exception -

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Not allowed to capture 'id' twice in the same pattern
```

Comment: Could you provide more information? A code snippet with your build file, the complete error and stacktrace, a sample HTTP request + response (with headers) would help. Is the provided `RouterFunction` the full extent of the application? Are you deploying annotated controllers as well?

Comment: Hi @BrianClozel, No it doesn't have any other deployed controller. (http://localhost:8080/student/output/1) works fine. But when I deploy same on Openshift platform, it throws 500 with exception on browser - (https://student-transformer-service.ocp.com/student/output/1). Exception - Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no configured error view, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Dec 18 01:42:20 UTC 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Not allowed to capture 'id' twice in the same pattern